# Mongoose saving dynamic array of subdocuments in one shot

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have searched high and low but haven't found a solution.

I am trying to save an array of subdocuments (that is dynamic).

```
Here's my schema:

    const EventSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  attendee:[ 
    {
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      status: {
        type: String
      }
    }]
});

Here's the route:

router.post('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  const {title, attendee: [{ email, name, status }] } = req.body

  try{  
    const newEvent = new Event({
        title,
        user: req.user.id,
        attendee: [{ email, name, status }]
    });

    const event = await newEvent.save();
    if (!event) throw Error('Something went wrong saving the event');

    res.status(200).json(event);

   
  catch (e) {
  res.status(400).json({ msg: e.message });
}
});
```

Currently I am only getting 1 element in the array to save.

The items in the array will always be different.

I don't have the option of creating the "event" first and then adding "attendees".

```
Example of input:

{
    "title": "Something",
    "attendee": [
      {
        "email": "email@gmail.com",
        "name": "Bob"
      },
             {
        "email": "sandwich@gmail.com",
        "name": "Martha"
      }
    ]
  }

Output:

{
  "_id": "5ef1521f06a67811f74ba905",
  "title": "Something",
  "user": "5ecdaf3601cd345ddb73748b",
  "attendee": [
    {
      "_id": "5ef1521f06a67811f74ba906",
      "email": "email@gmail.com",
      "name": "Bob"
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of destructuring for the one object of the array, you can get the whole array of attendee from the request body and save it as it is.

```
router.post('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  
  const eventObj =  {
  user: req.user.id,
  title : req.body.title, 
  // get the whole array of attendee objects from the request
  attendee: req.body.attendee 
  } 

  try{  
    const newEvent = new Event(eventObj);

    const event = await newEvent.save();
    if (!event) throw Error('Something went wrong saving the event');

    res.status(200).json(event);

   
  catch (e) {
  res.status(400).json({ msg: e.message });
}
});
```

Comment: Lol, I feel dumb. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm now trying to check wether an attendee is a registered user or not before saving with the following: const attendee = await User.findOne({email: attendees.email});
    if (!attendee) throw Error("User doesn't exist.");

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should not destructure `attendee` and insert into your new `Event` every attendee (choosing which key to insert in database).

```
const {
  title,
  attendee,
} = req.body;

const newEvent = new Event({
  title,
  user: req.user.id,

  attendee: attendee.map(x => ({
    email: x.email,
    name: x.name,
    status: x.status,
  })),
});
```

Comment: Salut Grégory, I ended up using your solution since now I want to search the email of the attendees and check whether they are registered users or not. I'm having trouble making the for loop for that.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean having trouble with the loop? How can I help?

Comment: I've created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430469/find-subdocument-object-in-another-db?noredirect=1#comment112177810_63430469 thanks for your help mon ami!