# Find subdocument object in another db

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to check each email of attendees and see if they are a registered user. If not, I will send them an email (not yet coded, will do later).

Here's the event and user schema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
     
const Event = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    attendees:[
     {email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
     },
     name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
     },
     status: {
     type: String
     }}
   ]
}); 

router.post('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  const {title,
    attendees
  } = req.body

  if (!title) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Please enter a title' });
  }

  try{  
    const newEvent = new Event({
        title,
        user: req.user.id,
        attendees:  attendees.map(x => ({
          email: x.email,
          name: x.name,
          status: x.status,
        })),
    });

const attendeeExists = await User.findOne({"attendees.email":email});
if (!attendeeExists) throw Error("User doesn't exist. Send email");
```

The last two lines are giving me an error: email is not defined.
Not sure what I'm missing.

This works in the user routes:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email });
```

Comment: Don't see `email` defined in the code you have posted, hence the error. Where is this `email` coming from? Please share more details.

Comment: Added the schema for Event & User.

Comment: So you want to test if any of the attendees 's email exists in db or not, which is coming from `req.body` in `attendees` variable?

Comment: Yes exactly! I want to check attendees email with user email.

Answer (score 0):

For checking any of the attendee's email found, `.find()` with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) can be used which'll return the users found with any of the email ids.

```
/*collect all emails to test*/
const emails = attendees.map((a) => a.email);
const attendeesFound = await User.find({ "email": { $in: emails } });
```

Another Mongoose syntax wihich does the same thing as above:

```
/*collect all emails to test*/
const emails = attendees.map((a) => a.email);
const attendeesFound = await User.find({}).where("email").in(emails);
```

Comment: When running a test, the "attendeesFound" is returning an empty array, even if I'm sending an email that is in the user db. The "emails" is returning the list of emails from the input correctly.

Comment: @morethan1 Please check now! have updated the queries according to the `schema` of `User` which I missed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ambianBeing, your solution helped me get a working model.

```
const email = attendees.map((a) => a.email);
const attendeesFound = await User.find({email});
```